# Is it possible to overlay SpatialLinesDataFrame and SpatialPolygonDataFrame

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, gis, clip

I am wondering if this is possible to do this R .

I have one data as SpatialLinesDataFrame and another as spatialPolygonDataFrame. Is it possible to overlay these two data ?

When I try to overlay these I get the following error:

```
  jd <- overlay(res,hello) 
  Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :  unable to find an inherited method for function      
  ‘overlay’ for signature ‘"SpatialLinesDataFrame", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"’
```

In the above code res is the SpatialLinesDataFrame and hello is SpatialPolygonDataFrame.

I have an shapefile and then I have data points with x,yand z
coordinates. I want to show the contour lines on the shapefile.

The procedure I used is using akima package to do the interpolation. The
code I used to interpolate is

```
fld <- interp(x,y,z)
```

Then I changed this to spatial object by using following code:

```
res <-ContourLines2SLDF(contourLines(fld))
```

The above command would store the contourlines as spatial data.

Then I read the shapefile and I plot both shapefile and res as follows:

```
p1 <-
spplot(hello,sp.layout=list(list("sp.lines",res)),col="blue",lwd=0,fill="grey",colorkey=F)
p1
```

"hello" is my shapefile and "res" is the object I created as shown above.

The problem is contour stored in "res" extends beyond the shapefile. So I
want to clip that contour with the shapefile and only display the contour
within the shapefile area.

So I am looking for a way to clip the contour layer with the polygon layer.

I have attached the image I got with my code.
[image]

In the image you can see the lines out of the shapefile. I also want to know
how can I display the contour levels on the map.

Thank you so much.

Jdbaba

I also want to know what does overlay does exactly. Does it intersect the area of both the data ?

Thank you.

Comment: A reproducible example will up your chances of getting a helpful reply.

Comment: Thank you I will add the more detailed information on the post.

Comment: There's a lot of examples in `rgeos` package. Can you adopt one of them?

Comment: @Roman Lustrik Thank you for your response. Can you show me some of the examples so that I would be in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using contour lines? Your lake is such an irregular shape that clipped contour lines will be a mess and also impossible to label. Why not stick with the gridded output and plot it with something like fifty shades of grey? Contour lines HAVE TO be labelled or otherwise identifiable with a given value, otherwise its impossible to tell if it goes up or down.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Could you tell me what do you think is the best approach ? Creating just the point plot using spplot like you suggested last time ? Is there any other packages that creates smooth shades of grey ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to clip your lines to the polygon extent. Use `gIntersection` from the `rgeos` package. Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(rgeos)
xx <- SpatialPoints(coords=matrix(data=c(0,0), nrow=1))
xx <- gBuffer(spgeom=xx, width=1)
yy <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(matrix(c(-1,1,-1,1), nrow=2)), ID=1)))
zz <- gIntersection(yy, xx)
```

You can overlay the plot like so:

```
plot(xx)
plot(zz, add = TRUE, col = "blue")
```

Comment: Hi Noah, Thank you so so much. This is exactly what I was looking for past few days. These bunch of code worked like charm. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Noah's answer has worked quite well for me. However, the output of his answer is a SpatialLines object, which cannot be saved as a shape file.

My two cents here is about how you can convert your SpatialLines object into a SpatialLinesDataFrame and save it as a shape file.

```
res.df <- fortify(res) # create data frame of res, your original SpatialLinesDataFrame

data <- data.frame(id = unique(res.df$id)) # get ids of road segments
rownames(data) <- data$id

# transform SpatialLines object into SpatialLinesDataFrame
zzSpatialLineDF <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(zz, data) # convert zz object keeping road ids


# 5 Save Shape File to your working directory
writeOGR(zzSpatialLineDF, dsn = '.', layer ='zzSpatialLineDF', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```